# Relation between "syntax" and "grammar" in CS

Tags: terminology, context-free, formal-grammars, programming-languages, syntax

I do sure that "grammar" and "syntax" is two different thing in CS, e.g

> Syntax of Java language is defined by a context-free grammar.

My question are

What is different in definitions of "grammar" and "syntax" in CS?

What is relation between them, can we describe it by using set theory?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_(programming_languages).  I suggest doing more research before asking in the future.  If your question is answered in the obvious place in standard resources (Wikipedia, textbooks), you probably haven't done enough research before asking.  There's little point in us repeating material already widely available in standard resources.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your quote has the following operational meaning for *syntax* in the context of programming languages:

> The *syntax* of a programming language is the set of all syntactically valid programs.

The syntax only describes what the valid programs look like; *semantics* gives them meaning – tells you how to execute them.

The set of all valid programs is an example of a [formal language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language); a *formal language* is just a collection of strings. There are many ways of describing formal languages. One of them is through [formal grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar), which you can think of as a type of formula that describes a formal language. [Context-free grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) are a restricted type of formal grammars. As such, they cannot describe all formal languages, but only [context-free languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language). (General grammars also describe only some of the formal languages; this is due to the fact that there are countably many grammars but uncountably many formal languages.) Summarizing:

> A *grammar* is one way to specify a formal language.

Finally, let me mention that the set of syntactically valid Java programs actually cannot be described by a context-free grammar; only some features can be described. Context-free grammars cannot enforce, for example, that a variable not be defined twice in the same context. However, once we abstract away such details (for example, by replacing variable names with generic placeholders), the resulting set of syntactically valid Java programs does lend itself (perhaps) to being captured by a context-free grammar.

*Parsing* (in our context) is the process of reading the source code of a Java program and constructing its *parse tree*, which is its structure as seen from the perspective of the context-free grammar. The parse tree captures the semantics of the program in a form amenable to further manipulation in the compilation process. Abstracting away details such as variable names and values of constants relegates this information into the form of *parameters*, but doesn't obstruct the control structure of the program.

Comment: So how do you define *syntactically valid*? It's what a program is when ... well, what?  A Java compiler doesn't throw any syntax errors on them?

Comment: @reinierpost That's right. A syntactically valid program is one which has no syntax errors.

Comment: So what is a syntax error? I just want to make sure we can eventually end up with a definition that doesn't already have the word *syntax* or *syntactical* in it.  E.g. I'm fine with letting a particular piece of software be the judge, but that has its problems. (A bugfix that causes a syntax error to be reported that previously wasn't will then change the syntax of Java.)

Comment: @reinierpost Formal definitions are a nice pastime, but in reality this is an intuitive concept, some details of which might be contentious. For example, is importing a missing package a syntax error? I don't think so, but you can disagree. In practice, committees publish standards which include the syntax of programming languages, including Java, thus answering your question in an official manner.

Comment: I don't think this is about formality, but about ontology: what sort of thing is a programming language and what sort of thing is its syntax? I wanted to see it clarified that for you (as for me) it is basically something like a natural language: the language and its syntax are "out there" and formal definitions, such as grammars, mearly try to describe it.  Different views exist (e.g. "the grammar *is* the syntax").

Comment: @reinierpost This is a philosophical question and so out of scope here.

Comment: I disagree. As you can see, different views on this produce opposite answers to the question being posed here.

Comment: @reinierpost If you disagree, you are welcome to post another answer. Otherwise, these discussions belong to chat (in which I don't participate).